# Windows change msconfig statup selection on different drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, msconfig

I am running a computer with 2 drives which both have windows installed on them. I am currently logged in to windows installed on `drive a`  and want to change the statup selection in `msconfig` from `normal startup` tp `selective statrtup` without `use orginal boot configuration` in windows installed on `drive b`. I can not boot windows installed on `drive b`, but can access all files on it. Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Can you boot the second system with the Windows 10 DVD / USB and then do a startup Repair?  I think that may be as likely to work as trying to change MSCONFIG.

Comment: Provide your BCD configuration